# can't tap on a php included section on mobile

Tags: php, html

I have an HTML page where a form section is included like this :

```
<?php  include 'templates/register-form.php'?>
```

In a web browser there is no problem and everythig is working .

But on mobile , i can see the section , but cannot tap on it , the input doesn't react and neither the buttons .

What can it be? 
thanx!

the code below is the included section.

```
<form role="form">
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pull-right">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nusername"  language="en">username :</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm login-input"  name="nusername" placeholder="שם משתמש" value="<?php echo Input::get('username')?>">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pull-right">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fullname"  language="en">full name :</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm login-input"  name="fullname" placeholder="שם מלא" value="<?php echo Input::get('fullname')?>">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pull-right">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="npassword"  language="en">password :</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control input-sm login-input"  name="npassword" placeholder="שם מלא" value="<?php echo Input::get('password')?>">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pull-right">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password_again"  language="en">password again :</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control input-sm login-input"  name="password_again" placeholder="הקלד את הסיסמא שנית" value="<?php echo Input::get('password_again')?>">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pull-right">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email"  language="en">email:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control input-sm login-input"  name="email" placeholder="אי-מייל" value="<?php echo Input::get('email')?>">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pull-right">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="adress"  language="en">adress:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm login-input"  name="adress" placeholder="כתובת" value="<?php echo Input::get('adress')?>">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pull-right">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="phone"  language="en">phone:</label>
        <input type="tel" class="form-control input-sm login-input"  name="phone" placeholder="טלפון" value="<?php echo Input::get('phone')?>">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pull-right">
    <div class="form-group">
        <a  class="form-control input-sm register-button btn btn-success pull-left"  name="register-button" >הירשם</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you include it via an AJAX call?

Comment: It's unlikely that it is related to php as that is server-side. You should post the html / css / javacript involved.

Comment: I didn't included it via AJAX , this is part of the  HTML page . This is the section :      <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 content" > 
   <?php  include 'templates/register-form.php'?>
  </div>
 </div>

Comment: Please don't dump code in comments. Edit your original post to add any new information.

Comment: @ItayMiness That's not the code that matters.  What's the result of `include('templates/register-form.php')`?  Your server-side code is irrelevant.  Show us what the client-side code looks like.

Comment: I added the included section .

Answer (score 0):

In each field, your label attaches to the input field using the for-attribute. Safari connects for-attributes to id's, not names. Add the correct id to each of your inputs.

Example:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pull-right">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nusername"  language="en">username :</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm login-input" id="username" name="nusername" placeholder="שם משתמש" value="<?php echo Input::get('username')?>">
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, I suspect you just left it out of your example, but don't forget your  tag, which might cause some issues in the Browser.